# Blazor HTML Rendering of Page has a significant delay in loading

Tags: performance, blazor

I have the following html render for Blazor that is taking about 5 seconds to load. I use a small window to tell the user that it is loading but I am wondering if there was something I did to cause this to be slow. I have built a table in a separate html testing a render over a 1000 rows. It renders quickly. So I am at a loss for why this is rendering slow. I know there is a lot of code here but I am hoping that someone might find something or know something I don't know about rendering large database sets.

I tried putting in console.writeline(s) after each forloop. It seems to parse through the HTML fast! Then it takes like 5 seconds to process so its the processing part that seems to be taking forever. Not sure why. I'm not doing anything in blazor after the render. I placed a console.writeline in the function called when the page is done rendering and it takes time before that console.writeline is printed.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="input-group d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center rounded w-75 mx-auto py-4 header-sans-serif font-md">
        <div class="d-flex flex-nowrap flex-row">
            <input class="form-control rounded header"
               type="text"
               style="border-top-right-radius:0px !important; border-bottom-right-radius:0px !important;border-right:0 !important;"
               placeholder="Search"
               @bind-value="@SearchParameter">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-gradient m-0 py-1" @onclick="()=>Search()">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass font-md"
                    aria-hidden="true"
                    data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
                    data-bs-placement="bottom" title="Search"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="font-weight-bolder p-1 rounded justify-content-start ms-4">
            <div class="form-check form-switch d-flex flex-rows justify-content-start align-items-center">
                <input class="form-check-input me-2 ps-0 ms-0 font-lg" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" @onchange="(e)=>OnClickFrequenlyUsedSkills(e.Value!.ToString()!)">
                <label class="form-check-label text-center" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault" >Show Frequently<br />Used Skills</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            @if (ExpandAllFlag == false)
            {
                <button class="ms-4 btn btn-primary btn-custom btn-gradient" @onclick="()=>ExpandAll(true)">Expand All</button>
            }
            else
            {
                <button class="ms-4 btn btn-primary btn-gradient btn-custom " @onclick="()=>ExpandAll(false)">Collapse All</button>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    @for(int i = 0; i<pCharStat.pCharacter!.Categories.Count; i++)
    {
        CategoryCls pCategory = pCharStat.pCharacter.Categories[i];
        <div class="d-flex flex-row bg-expandbutton-background glass align-items-center rounded p-0 w-75 mx-auto border header-sans-serif font-md">
            <button class="d-flex flex-row btn justify-content-between align-items-center border-0 p-3 w-100 mx-auto"
                type="button"
                data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
                data-bs-target="#TargetBody_@pCategory.CategoryNameNS"
                aria-expanded="true"
                aria-controls="TargetBody_@pCategory.CategoryNameNS">
                <div class="nolineheight">
                    <div class="font-xl font-weight-bold">@pCategory.CategoryName</div>
                    <div class="font-md text-muted text-left">Cost: @pCategory.Cost</div>
                </div>
            </button>

            <div class="ms-3" style="flex-basis:50px;">
                <button class="btn"
                     data-bs-toggle="modal"
                     data-bs-placement="top"
                     data-bs-target="addskillmodal"
                     @onclick="()=>AddSkill(pCategory)"
                     title="Add Skill">
                    <i class='fa-solid fa-plus nolineheight hover-shadow font-md'></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div style="flex-basis:50px;">
                <button class="btn"
                 data-bs-toggle="modal"
                     data-bs-placement="top"
                    data-bs-target="addcategorymodal"
                 @onclick="()=>EditCategory(pCategory)"
                 title="Edit Category">
                    <i class='fa-solid fa-pencil nolineheight hover-shadow font-md'></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div style="flex-basis:50px;">
                <button class="btn"
                 data-bs-toggle="modal"
                     data-bs-placement="top"
                 @onclick="()=>DeleteCategory(pCategory)"
                 title="Delete Category">
                    <i class='fa-regular fa-trash-can nolineheight hover-shadow font-md'></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse" id="TargetBody_@pCategory.CategoryNameNS">
            <div class="card w-75 header-sans-serif mx-auto my-0 text-justify glass-blue rounded-1 border">
                <div class="card-body table-responsive ">
                    <table class="table table-sm table-hover header">
                        <thead class="font-md" style="border-bottom:1px solid grey;">
                            <tr>
                                <th class="ps-1">Skill Name</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Cost</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Ranks</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Rank<br />Bonus</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Stat<br />Bonus</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Talent<br />Bonus</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Other<br />Bonus</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Total<br />Bonus</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                            @foreach (SkillCls pSkill in pCategory.Skills)
                            {
                            string skillNS = pCharStat.pDatabase.CleanInput(pCategory.CategoryNameNS + pCharStat.pDatabase.CleanInput(pSkill.SkillName));

                                string backgroundcolor = "";
                            @if (pSkill.SkillName.Contains(SearchParameter) && SearchParameter != "")
                                {
                                    backgroundcolor = "alert alert-danger";
                                }
                                else if(ShowFrequentlyUsedSkills && pSkill.FrequentlyUsed)
                                {
                                    backgroundcolor = "alert alert-warning";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                backgroundcolor = "";
                                }
                                <tbody>
                                <tr class="py-0 my-0 @backgroundcolor" id="Target_@(skillNS)">
                                        <th class="ExpandedIconToggle align-middle smallcaps-off font-weight-normal font-md p-0"
                                            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                            data-bs-target="#TargetBody_@(skillNS)"
                                            aria-expanded="false"
                                            aria-controls="#TargetBody_@(skillNS)">


                                            @if (pSkill.SubSkillList.Count > 0)
                                            {
                                                <span class="text-expanded smallcaps-off">
                                                    <i class='fa-solid fa-plus me-2 p-0'
                                                       data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
                                                       data-bs-placement="top"
                                                        title="Show Subskills"></i>
                                                    @pSkill.SkillName
                                                </span>
                                                <span class="text-collapsed smallcaps-off">
                                                    <i class='fa-solid fa-minus me-2 text-collapsed'
                                                       data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
                                                       data-bs-placement="top"
                                                       title="Show Subskills"></i>
                                                @pSkill.SkillName
                                                </span>
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                <span>@pSkill.SkillName</span>
                                            }
                                        </th>
                                        <td class="text-center align-middle smallcaps-off font-weight-normal font-md p-0">
                                            @if(pCharStat.pCharacter.Professions.Count > 1)
                                            {
                                                if(pSkill.LockCost)
                                                {
                                                @pSkill.SkillCost
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                <span>*</span>
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                            @pSkill.SkillCost
                                            }
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="text-center align-middle smallcaps-off font-weight-normal font-md p-0">
                                            <span class='mx-0'>@pSkill.Ranks.Count</span>

                                            @if (!pSkill.SubSkillOnly)
                                            {
                                            <button class='btn p-0' @onclick="()=>EditRanks(pSkill)">
                                                <i class='fa-solid fa-pencil font-md ms-2'
                                                    data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
                                                    data-bs-placement="top"
                                                    data-bs-content="Update Ranks"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            <button class='btn p-0 invisible'>
                                                <i class='fa-solid fa-pencil font-md ms-2'
                                                   data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
                                                   data-bs-placement="top"
                                                   data-bs-content="Update Rank Information"></i>
                                            </button>

                                        }
                                    </td>
                                        <td class="text-center align-middle smallcaps-off font-weight-normal font-md p-0">
                                            @pSkill.RankBonus
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="text-center align-middle smallcaps-off font-weight-normal font-md p-0">
                                            @pSkill.StatBonus
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="text-center align-middle smallcaps-off font-weight-normal font-md p-0">
                                            @pSkill.TalentBonus
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="text-center align-middle smallcaps-off font-weight-normal font-md p-0">
                                            @pSkill.OtherBonus
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="text-center align-middle smallcaps-off font-weight-normal font-md p-0">
                                            @pSkill.TotalBonus
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="text-right p-0">
                                            <button class='mx-auto px-2 btn rounded-circle' role="button"
                                            @onclick="()=>AddSubSkill(pCategory, pSkill)">
                                                <i class='fa-solid fa-plus font-md' data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Add Subskill"></i>
                                            </button>
                                            <button class='btn px-2 rounded-circle' role="button"
                                            @onclick="()=>EditSkill(pCategory, pSkill)">
                                                <i class='fa-solid fa-pencil font-md' data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Edit Skill"></i>
                                            </button>
                                            <button class='btn px-2 rounded-circle' role="button"
                                            @onclick="()=>DeleteSkill(pCategory, pSkill)">
                                                <i class='fa-regular fa-trash-can font-md' data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Delete Skill"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>

                                @if (pSkill.SubSkillList.Count > 0)
                                {
                                string SphereName = "";
                                <tbody class="collapse" id="TargetBody_@(skillNS)">
                                
                                    @foreach (SubSkillCls pSubSkill in pSkill.SubSkillList)
                                    {
                                        string backgroundcolorsub = "";
                                        @if (pSubSkill.SkillName.Contains(SearchParameter) && SearchParameter != "")
                                        {
                                            backgroundcolorsub = "alert alert-danger";
                                        }
                                        else if (ShowFrequentlyUsedSkills && pSubSkill.FrequentlyUsed)
                                        {
                                            backgroundcolorsub = "alert alert-warning";
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            backgroundcolorsub = "";
                                        }
                                        @if(SphereName != pSubSkill.SphereName)
                                        {
                                            SphereName = pSubSkill.SphereName;
                                            <tr><td colspan="9" class="font-weight-bold smallcaps">@pSubSkill.SphereName</td></tr>
                                        }
                                        <tr class="@backgroundcolorsub" id="Target_@(pCategory.CategoryNameNS+pSkill.SkillNameNS+pSubSkill.SkillNameNS)">
                                            <th class="ps-4 align-middle smallcaps-off font-weight-normal font-md p-0">
                                                @if(pSkill.SkillName == "Spell Casting")
                                                {
                                                    @($"{pSubSkill.SphereName} - {pSubSkill.SkillName}")
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    @pSubSkill.SkillName;
                                                }
                                            </th>
                                            <td class="text-center align-middle smallcaps-off font-weight-normal font-md p-0">
                                                @if (pCharStat.pCharacter.Professions.Count > 1)
                                                {
                                                    if (pSubSkill.LockCost)
                                                    {
                                                        @pSubSkill.SkillCost
                                                    }
                                                    else 
                                                    {
                                                        <span>*</span>
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    @pSubSkill.SkillCost
                                                }
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center align-middle smallcaps-off font-weight-normal font-md p-0">
                                                <span class='mx-0'>
                                                    @pSubSkill.Ranks.Count
                                                </span>
                                                <button class='btn p-0' @onclick="()=>EditRanks(pSkill, pSubSkill)">
                                                    <i class='fa-solid fa-pencil font-md ms-2'
                                                        data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
                                                        data-bs-placement="top"
                                                        data-bs-content="Update Rank Information"></i>
                                                </button>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center align-middle smallcaps-off font-weight-normal font-md p-0">
                                                @pSubSkill.RankBonus
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center align-middle smallcaps-off font-weight-normal font-md p-0">
                                                @pSubSkill.StatBonus
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center align-middle smallcaps-off font-weight-normal font-md p-0">
                                                @pSubSkill.TalentBonus
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center align-middle smallcaps-off font-weight-normal font-md p-0">
                                                @pSubSkill.OtherBonus
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-center align-middle smallcaps-off font-weight-normal font-md p-0">
                                                @pSubSkill.TotalBonus
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="text-right">
                                                <button class='btn p-0 px-2 rounded-circle' @onclick="()=>EditSubSkill(pCategory, pSkill, pSubSkill)">
                                                    <i class='fa-solid fa-pencil font-md' data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-content="Edit SubSkill"></i>
                                                </button>
                                                <button class='btn p-0 px-2 rounded-circle' @onclick="()=>DeleteSubSkill(pSkill, pSubSkill)">
                                                    <i class='fa-regular fa-trash-can font-md' data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-content="Delete SubSkill"></i>
                                                </button>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    }
                                    </tbody>
                                }
                            }
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center my-4">
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-custom btn-gradient" @onclick="()=>AddCategory()">
            Add Category
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-gradient btn-custom ms-2" @onclick="()=>BackToMainScreen()">
            Back to Main Screen
        </button>
    </div>
    @if(pCharStat.pCharacter.Professions.Count > 1)
    {
        <div class="mb-4"> *Skill costs for when a character has multiple professions varies based on the profession they are leveling.</div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: What is `pCharStat.pCharacter!.Categories` ?

Comment: Is it Blazor Server Side or WebAssembly? Have you investigated loading of JS in the browser's developer tools?

Comment: Rerendering large junks of data takes a while. I suggest you use the `<Virtualize>` component for it :)

Comment: [Polite]  I can see a staggering amount of code in a page.  My pages contain Forms which contain control components.  In your case I'd be isolating and debugging each form and then drilling down into those to see who was the slow culprit.  There's probably one data retrieval that is causing the problem, but find it in our haystack is not a trivial task.   All I see is a wall of code and no context.

Comment: @MarvinKlein is right, this is a lot of components to render, you should consider virtualization or async rendering, how many records you are expecting in `pCharStat.pCharacter!.Categories`?

Comment: Not too many records. Anywhere between 100 and 200 records. Perhaps just the rendering of the records themselves in HTML takes a while regardless. I have other places where this happens and it definitely is due to rendering about 100 to 200 rows.